# Function not getting called in Unreal

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I'm new to Unreal. I'm part of a research project and I'm trying to learn the engine better as I proceed but there is something which has got me stuck for quite some time. I have a private function `GetGrids` declared in the .h file. I'm trying to call it in .cpp file but the control never enters that function. I have put a breakpoint in that function which which is not hit at all. I tried restarting visual studio, rebuilding a solution but nothing seems to work.

```
#include "RoboRev_Win.h"
#include "MapsManager.h"

AMapsManager::AMapsManager(const FObjectInitializer& ObjectInitializer)
    :Super(ObjectInitializer)
{
    m_row = MAP_SIZE;
    m_column = MAP_SIZE;
    m_startPoint = FVector(0, 0, 90);
    m_IsMapCreated = false;
    PrimaryActorTick.bStartWithTickEnabled = true;
}

void AMapsManager::Tick(float DeltaSeconds)
{
    Super::Tick(DeltaSeconds);
    if (!m_IsMapCreated)
        CreateMap();
}

AGrid* AMapsManager::GetGridWithID(int _ID)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= GRID_SIZE*GRID_SIZE; i++)
    {
        AGrid *_Grid = m_Grids[i];
        if (_Grid->ID == _ID)
        {
            return _Grid;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

void AMapsManager::GetGrids()
{
    int a, b, c;
    a = 1;
    b = 2;
    c = 3;
    int sum;
    sum = a + b + c;
    printf("");
    printf("");
}

void AMapsManager::CreateMap()
{
    UWorld* const _World = GetWorld();
    if (_World)
    {
        m_IsMapCreated = true;

        FActorSpawnParameters _Parameters;
        _Parameters.Owner = this;
        _Parameters.Instigator = Instigator;

        FVector _SpawnPosition;

        FRotator _Rotator(0, 0, 0);

        _SpawnPosition = FVector(0, 0, 0);

        originalX = _SpawnPosition.X - ((MAP_SIZE / 2)*GRID_SIZE);
        _SpawnPosition.X = originalX;
        _SpawnPosition.Y = originalX;

        _CurrentID = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i <= m_row; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= m_column; j++)
            {
                AGrid *_Grid = static_cast<AGrid *>(_World->SpawnActor(m_GridPawn, &_SpawnPosition, &_Rotator, _Parameters));
                _Grid->ID = _CurrentID;
                m_Grids.push_back(_Grid);
                _SpawnPosition.X += GRID_SIZE;
                _CurrentID++;
            }
            _SpawnPosition.Y += GRID_SIZE;
            _SpawnPosition.X = originalX;
        }
    }
    int _MapIDs[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25 };
    int k = 9;
    for (int l = 0; l < k; l++)
    {
        //AGrid *_Grid = GetGridWithID(_MapIDs[l]);
        //_Grid->ChangeMaterial();
        this->GetGrids();
    }
}
```

Don't mind what the function is doing. It is just a test function.

This is the declaration in .h file

```
private:
       void GetGrids();
```

please help!

Comment: Before determining why `GetGrids` is *not* being called, you're *sure* `CreateMap` **is** being called ? Did you put a breakpoint at the beginning of *that* function and step through *it*?

Comment: @Aadithya How do you know that The function isn't being called? You just print two empty strings, so you won't see any output even if it is being called.

Comment: Yes, CreateMap is being called. I put a breakpoint and step through the code

@TheDDestroyer, I have put a breakpoint in that function which is not hit

Comment: @Aadithya Ah, okay. I'm pretty new to Visual Studio so I don't know how to use the breakpoint tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Visual Studio compiler is configured to pretty aggressively optimize the code and calls of your functions. Since your GetGrids() method does not that has any influence on the running program, the compiler just drops the call altogether or inlines stuff like print.
Even when debugging with breakpoints you can not jump into a method that the compiler optimized away.

Try adding something like this to your function, so you can see it in the running engine.

```
UE_LOG(LogExec, Warning, TEXT("GetGrids() was called."));
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Can you tell me how can I reduce the optimization? Basically how do I tell Visual studio to not that ? Because I use it for another project and this does not happen there. I don't know why it would depend on project.

Comment: As far as I know you can and should not reduce it. The problem is that the project file and all configurations are automagically created by the Unreal Engine. Even if you were to change it, the engine would just overwrite it again.